# Problem while updating images with hooks?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I can't update an image with hooks. The image stays the same when I change the hook state pressing a button. The console log just logs "1". How can I fix this?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Image,
  Center,
  NativeBaseProvider
} from "native-base";

const test1 = require('../src/img/testimg.png');
const test2 = require('../src/img/test2img.png');
const tests = {test1,test2};

export const Example = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(tests.test1);

  return (
    <View>
        <Image
          source={selected}
          width= "100%"
          height="100%"
          alt="image"
        />
        <Button onPress={() => {setSelected(tests.test2);console.log(selected)}}>Change Image</Button>
    </View>
  )
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
      <Center>
        <Example/>
      </Center>
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setSelected` function is not synchronous, so `console.log(selected)` will not log the new value.

However, because `setSelected` triggers a re-render, you can call `console.log(selected)`, just before the `return`, and have it display the new value.

```js
export const Example = () => {

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(tests.test1);

  console.log(selected);

  return (
    <View>
        <Image
          source={selected}
          width= "100%"
          height="100%"
          alt="image"
        />
        <Button onPress={() => {
           setSelected(tests.test2);
        }}>Change Image</Button>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: The Image doesn't change. The console log now changes but the Image does not change. What can it be?

Comment: Was the image changing before? I ask because if the value of `selected` is changing, then perhaps the `Image` component might be the culprit refusing to update even though it has its new `source` value.

Comment: No, the image wasn't changing. I think it migth be the Image component but I have no Idea how to solve it. I saw a post in from React doing exactly the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378775/how-to-change-image-on-button-click-with-react-hooks

Comment: Maybe try `import` instead of `require`? Or use a url for the image, passed as `<Image source={{ uri: "./path/to/testimg.png" }}`. If these don't work, I'd check [NativeBase's Image docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/image#with-nexts-require-statement) for help.

Comment: Ok. Tried both and got two diffrent errors. Changing the Image source to the uri one I got a Console Warning saying "Unsupported uri scheme! Uri is:". And with the import I get the same result as before the Image not changing. In the NativeBase docs it recommended using uri: selected.default.src and I dont understand why but I get Undefined is not an object referring to .default.src.